# Database schema: User Team administration

Tags: mysql, database-design, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have **users**, who are members of **many teams** through a **membership** table. Each team has one administrator.

My question is:

Should the **admin column** be a boolean in the **membership** table, or an integer (id of user) in the **team** table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simple is, yes: in membership table as that is the link between a User and a Team. In that case you would be more flexible to add for example 2 administrators. The other way around is also a valid one, considering it secures to have explicitly 1 administrator.

The disadvantage is for example that there is a relation which you should enforce so admin_id always links to a User which is really a member of the Team. So on delete you should check whether this admin is really still available.

A bit further thinking: Consider whether you have multiple roles, if that's the case you might use a more complex but flexible solution like ACL's and things.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably asign a boolean to the membership just in case my client changes his mind on the number of admins.